# Illustrated children's book about trip to Moon

Tags: story-identification, space, childrens-novel, moon

I remember reading a book about a trip to the Moon in the late 1970s or early 1980s. It was an illustrated hardback with a large page size, but not very thick - I'd guess fewer than 100 pages. The content was very educational, always explaining the science behind each scene.

Two details of style of which I'm not 100% certain:

- The narration was second person present tense.
- The colour scheme of the illustrations was black, white, and turquoise.

Four scenes that I remember:

- A comment on how good the view of Earth is just after leaving the atmosphere, followed by "Why not open the window for a better view?" and an explanation that you can't do that because there is no air at this altitude.
- The passenger cabin of the spacecraft had a flight attendant, tethered with a cable to avoid drifting while in freefall.
- In low Earth orbit, an astronaut has just completed a repair on a space station and pats the surface, satisfied with a job well done; he starts to drift away from the space station and has to throw some of his tools in order to reverse his motion and return.
- Towards the end of the book, there was a scene with a farm in a sealed dome on the surface of the Moon.

Comment: What was science-fictional about it?

Comment: @user14111: The plot of the story was a fictional trip to the Moon, and the technology was quite speculative - slightly more advanced than the present, and significantly more advanced than than the 1970s and 1980s.